# C++/GNUPlot heatmap with sparse data?

Tags: c++, plot, gnuplot, heatmap, density-plot

I'm just trying to mimic the following python code in C++ using gnuplot:

```
H, x, y = np.histogram2d(xs, ys, bins=200)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x[:-1], y[:-1], indexing='ij')
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, H, cmap = "hot")
plt.colorbar()
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

My c++ code already has the facilities to generate the x,y values and plot using gnuplot. I've done heat maps in c++/gnuplot before, but in those cases I had x, y, z data for each point in the desired range of the plot. What is an efficient way to do this if you only have sparse data?

Comment: Your code is not usable as is: it's missing the `numpy` and `matplotlib` imports and the definition of the `xs` and `ys`. For sparse data interpolation with gnuplot you might want to have a look at `set dgrid3d`.

Answer (score 1):

gnuplot interpolates gridded data with

```
set dgrid3d 200,200
# set pm3d + your options for the heat map
splot dataf
```

`dgrid3d` has a number of different interpolation routines available, check `help dgrid3d`. I think you want the "`box`" option to simply bin your data.

Comment: GIven n lines of sparse data in my input file in form "x y z" I've tried doing variants of "set dgrid3d n,n box", "set pm3d map", "set output "o.eps", "splot "in.txt"" and always end up with an empty plot. [Here](http://pastebin.com/VxdWcZVU) is an example of my data.

Comment: I think you want a grid with something like n^(1/3) rows and columns. Why eps? Have you forgotten to "set term postscript eps"? Use your default interactive terminal for testing! Does it work without pm3d? Don't go for maximum complexity when testing! Boil your problem down until it vanishes, to identify the exact problem!